# Exposing WCF soap service as async Task<T> from client?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, soap, async-await

I'm connecting to a SOAP service from Windows Phone 7.1. The service proxy has the `Get____Async` methods and `Get_____Completed` events.
I'm building a service class in my client that wraps the call to the SOAP service.

Can I somehow wrap it such that it's interface becomes:

```
public NNNNService
{
    public async Task<List<NNNNNN>> GetNNNNN(A a, B b, C c)
    {
        // ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show how exactly does the method and the event look like? What have you tried?

Comment: @svick The method and the event is the Soap proxy generated methods from "Add service reference". I haven't tried anything, since I don't know if it's possible or not. The examples I've seen seems to wrap using Begin/End methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh873178.aspx

Comment: That article has exactly what you need. Specifically look at the section [Tasks and the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh873178.aspx#EAP).

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the EAP into the TAP using the following pattern:

```
public static class NNNNServiceExtensions
{
    public static Task<ReturnType> MethodNameTaskAsync(this NNNNService service, A a)
    {
        if (service == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();


        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ReturnType>();

        EventHandlerType handler = null;
        handler = (s, o) =>
        {
            service.MethodNameCompleted -= handler;
            tcs.TrySetCompleted(o.Result);
        };

        service.MethodNameCompleted += handler;
        try
        {
            service.MethodNameAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            service.MethodNameCompleted -= handler;
            throw;
        }

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

With optional support for cancellation, progress reporting, etc. Sometimes it is hard to specify return type. In case your Completed event uses EventArgs, you can adjust the code in the following way:

```
public static Task MethodNameTaskAsync(this NNNNService service, A a)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
}
```